# When using auto-generated TableAdapters, what is the suggested way to deal with repeated instantiation?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, xsd

I am using the .xsd dataset thingies (which I hate) to auto-generate TableAdapter classes for some backend code.
I have not really used these before, tending to favour manual commands and stored procs whenever possible (for various speed-induced reasons: those xsds play hell with dynamic tables and really large amounts of columns), and am finding myself instantiating a TableAdapter in a large number of my methods, so my question is this:

Will the auto-generated code automatically streamline itself so that a full adapter class is not created on an instatiation, and instead share some static data (such as connection information), and if not would it be better for me to have some sort of singleton/static class provider that can give me access to their methods when needed without the overhead of creating a new adapter every time I want to get some information?

Cheers, Ed

Comment: Is there really that much overhead for instanciation of a TA?  The only thing I see in its constructor is `this.ClearBeforeFill = true;`  And it's CommandCollection and Connection properties are only set once during the lifetime of the TA.....meaning the overhead of setting things up only occurs when you make your first call to one of its public methods.....the Fill method, for example.  So as long as it stays in scope, I wouldn't expect any performance issues.  Am I way off base here??

Comment: That is kind of close to the answer I'm after to be honest, I'm looking to find out if, as you say, there's no performance hit for creating a new one each time I want to run a command (not quite literally, but very close: the code that is using these is rather spagetti-like due to system complexities), or if I should be creating a cached provider model to serve these when I need them.

Comment: Maybe use DotTrace to verify my claim.  (BTW...i'm using VS2005)  

One thing that I typically do, since there is a connection string put in at design time, is to make an overload constructor in a partial class for the table adapter which accepts and sets the production connection string, not the design time string.  This, however, does have some cost, as it sets up the connection at instanciation.

Comment: Example:
`    public partial class myTableAdapter
    {
        public myTableAdapter(string sConnectionString)
            : this()
        {
            // swap connection string
            this._connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            this._connection.ConnectionString = sConnectionString;
            Connection = _connection;
        }
    }
`

Comment: sorry....the back ticks to present code didn't work there....but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about the performance you could always run a benchmark to see what the performance hit, if any, is.

Sorry you didn't find my answer useful.

My point was that while you had received responses they all seemed to be subjective and not based on hard data. So if you had some reason to be concerned that there was a performance hit in your particular application you should measure it.

There is no reason to refactor one area for performance unless there is an actual problem.

Comment: I could: or I could ask on stackoverflow and save myself some time effort, and see if there's any form of group consensus . . oh, wait  a second...

Answer (score 1):

I actually tend to instanciate a very low number of adapters (usually only one of each type). I never tried using them as on the stack variables (instantiated when needed), so I never ran into your question, but I understand your concern.

From what I know the aqdapters themselves may be quite heavyweight in instancing, but the real killer is the connection. What I do is I mark the adapter's Connection modifier as `Public` in the .xsd designer so I can assign the property whatever I need it to use, and maintain a tight grip on the opening and closing of connections:

```
void Load() {
  using (SqlConnection conn = ...) {
    conn.Open();
    invoicesAdapter.Connection = conn;
    customersAdapter.Connection = conn;
    invoicesAdapter.Fill(dataSet.Invoices);
    customersAdapter.Fill(dataSet.Customers);
  }
}

void Save() {
  using (SqlConnection conn = ...) {
    conn.Open();
    invoicesAdapter.Connection = conn;
    customersAdapter.Connection = conn;
    invoicesAdapter.Update(dataSet);
    customersAdapater.Update(dataSet);
  }
}
```

I ommitted transaction control and error handling for brevity.